# What's the maximum length of the error message on AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I've been struggling with a call to AWS API Gateway where the call returns a 500 "Internal server error" instead a 400 error which is the expected one. After some debugging I've found that this is caused by an excessive length in the message sent to the "errorMessage".

What's the maximum length for this "errorMessage"?

Answer (score 0):

After some binary searching, I found that the limit seems to be 2199 characters. Sending an error message with 2200 or more characters generates a 500 HTTP status with an "Internal server error" message.

I guess a pending question would be where is this documented.